# HTML App for Mac/Windows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to create a program coded in HTML/CSS/JS, I already looked at cordova and phonegap, the only problem here is that I don't want to create an iOS or Android app, I want to create a Mac/Windows App. As far as I know there isn't the possibility in cordova or phonegap to create a Mac/Windows App (even though I believe I saw something similar to this in an old version of phonegap). So, do anyone of you have any idea how to make this possible?

Greetz,
Zocker3333.

Comment: You can make HTML apps for Windows, but I think for Mac you have to use either Objective-C or Swift, or you could use C# which can run on Mac with Mono

Comment: ...or just make a web app

Comment: Well I was hoping to create a game that way. The best example here is "Game Dev Tycoon", it is available on Steam, runs on Mac and Windows (and I think Linux too), and is written in HTML (or at least the biggest part of it).

Comment: You could always launch your app in a Chrome window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at [nodewebkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit). This can build HTML/JS based applications for Windows, Mac and Linux and is based around Node.JS